# Related Rates Calculus - Confused About What dx/dt, dy/dt and dx/dy mean

Tags: calculus, related-rates

[image: Related Rates Image]

Hello, I am confused as to how they got 5y in this problem when they multiplied dx/dy by dy/dt in the fourth line.

I am also confused as to what dx/dt and dx/dy and dy/dt mean.

Comment: Have you learned the chain rule?

Comment: Yes I have. I learned it a week or two ago.

Comment: $\tfrac{dx}{dt}$ is the derivative of $x(t)$ with respect to $t$, that is, $x'(t)$. Same for $\tfrac{dx}{dt}$. The expression $\tfrac{dx}{dy}$ is the derivative of $x$ as a function of $y$. Here, you have $x(y) = \tfrac 12(y^2-1)$ and therefore $\tfrac{dx}{dy} = y$.

Comment: Where'd you get the 1/2(y^2 -1) from?

Comment: see asmath's comment above, or my comment below.  All roads lead to Rome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have been more obvious if that had inserted a line after line 3 which read:

$$\frac{dx}{dy}=y $$

Do you see why? (just differentiate line 3 w.r.t *y*).

They told you $$\frac{dy}{dt}=5$$ so line 5 is just putting the values in for each term.

If you look back into the history of math, there is a fascinating distinction of notation between Lagrange and Leibnitz.  Lagrange wrote $$y=f(x)$$and $$y'=f'(x)$$
Leibnitz came up with the alternate notation of $$y=f(x)$$ so $$\frac{dy}{dx}=d\frac{f(y)}{dx}$$
Leibnitz' notation allows a lot more 'clever' use of fraction-like quantities, which usually work out - but can lead to problems if things aren't quite right (but you must be careful!).

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz%27s_notation

Comment: How can you explain dx/dy being equal to y?

Comment: $$x=\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{1}{2]$$  so, $$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{2y}[2}$$  This is classic trick to fool you; if confused, make $$y=\frac{1}{2}(x^2-1)$$, take the derivative w.r.t. x, then substitute y=x and x=y and you will get it.  (They are simply trying to confuse you since we always say $$y=f(x)$$, not $$x=f(y)$$).  I think if you do that all will work out (I am , in fact quite certain of it).

Comment: I have no idea what you just did. There are a bunch of dollar signs and stuff.

Comment: Markup problem.  they are just trying to confuse you by making $x=f(y)$, not the usual $y=f(x)$ $.   x=y^2/2-1/2$.  
proceed from there.  find $\frac{dx}{dy}$. hint: $\frac{dx}{dy}=1$.

Comment: glad you are at least awake and hunting for answers. This is well within your grasp, though not how I would teach it. Too many tricks lead to confusion,not mastery, for the student - and do not reflect well on the teacher.

Comment: Does that make sense?

Comment: You would have to show me on a whiteboard or something. Because through what you wrote I do not understand, but I thank you for your tenacity in helping me.  You can go to this whiteboard to help me haha if you'd like. I appreciate sincerely your time, kind sir. You're great. : www.webwhiteboard.com/board/6ezztmwr

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{dy}{dt}$ and $\frac{dx}{dt}$ are just another way to denote derivatives of functions. $\frac{dy}{dt}$ is equivalent to $y'(t)$. Likewise, $\frac{dx}{dt}$ means the same thing as $x'(t)$. This notation is called Leibniz's notation because it was Leibniz who introduced it.

If you differentiate both sides of the equation $y^2-1=2x$ with respect to $t$ (since $x$ and $y$ are functions of $t$), you will get this:

$$2y\frac{dy}{dt}=2\frac{dx}{dt}\implies \frac{dx}{dt}=y\frac{dy}{dt}$$

$\frac{dy}{dt}$ is given. You also know that $x=12$. This means that at some point $t_0$, $x$ is equal to $12$. But since $y$ is a function of the same quantity, what would it be equal to at the same point $t_0$ when $x$ is $12$? Well, use the relationship between $y$ and $x$ that you're given—$y(t)=\sqrt{2x(t)+1}$:
$$
y(t_0)=\sqrt{2x(t_0)+1}\\
y(t_0)=\sqrt{2\cdot 12+1}\\
y(t_0)=5\\y=5
$$

Just plug all the things that you now know into the expression that we came up with a few lines above:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=5\cdot 5 = 25$$